# Изменение значения переменной php в javascript

Tags: jquery, php, html, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Можно ли через скрипт изменить значение переменной php?

Есть меню:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sky text-uppercase btn-sm" id="btn_p"></button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-sky text-uppercase btn-sm" id="btn_m"></button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-sky text-uppercase btn-sm" id="btn_w"></button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-sky text-uppercase btn-sm" id="btn_s"></button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-sky text-uppercase btn-sm" id="btn_i"></button>
```

Ниже с php:

```
$news = new RSS_Pars($url)
```

Возможно ли реализовать, чтобы при нажатии каждой из кнопок меню поставляло свой url в переменную? Если да, то как?

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны понимать, что PHP - это сервер, js - клиент. Сервер уже отдал данные в ответе, и процесс завершен. Все PHP-переменные уже в прошлом. Чтобы что-то сделать в PHP, Вам нужно создать еще один запрос. Без обновления страницы это [AJAX](http://javascript.ru/ajax/intro).

**UPD:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn ..." data-link="http://link1.com"></button>
<button type="button" class="btn ..." data-link="http://link2.com"></button>
<script>
$('button').click(function(){ //при клике
    $.ajax({ //отправляем ajax-запрос
        type: "POST", //тип (POST, GET, PUT, etc)
        url: "/Your/Handler/Url/", //УРЛ Вашего обработчика
        data: { xmlUrl: $(this).attr('data-link') } //сами данные, передается POST[xmlUrl] со значением из data-link нажатой кнопки
    })
    .done(function( res ) { //при успехе (200 статус)
        $('#result').html(res) //заменяем блок с id="result" полученной строкой от сервера.
    });
});
</script>
```

В самом PHP скрипте по адресу `/Your/Handler/Url/` формируете HTML для выдачи обратно клиенту. Вообще Вы можете формировать и JSON, и все, что хотите, что Вам удобнее будет обрабатывать на клиенте для выдачи. То, что Вы сформируете, придет в переменной res.

Comment: Мне бы пример подобной задачи, было бы отлично.

Comment: Их кучи в интернете. Гуглите "ajax примеры". Из вопроса не совсем понятно, что именно Вам нужно.

Comment: Я передаю адрес xml файла в $url и разбираю его,вывожу нужное мне.
но xml файлов много поэтому хочу реализовать меню где при нажатии кнопки менялось значение $url, ну и уже разбирается другой файл и выводится.